# Unable to add Series to Dataframe using append

Tags: python, pandas

It keeps returning empty dataframe. Not very sure why. I also named my `columns` in `df_group` to match `g_row`. I also tried `pd.concate`. Still empty dataframe

```
df_group = pd.DataFrame()
added = []
for i, g_row in df.iterrows():
    if i not in added:
        print g_row #not empty; type(g_row) Series
        df_group.append(g_row, ignore_index=True)
        added.append(i)

print df_group #empty
```

Comment: Looks like you want to drop duplicate index rows in `df`? Why not do `df[~df.index.duplicated()].reset_index(drop=True)`?

Comment: @zero yeah I was thinking of that, looks pretty inefficient but I have one column that changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`append` does not work inplace. This will work `df_group = df_group.append(g_row, ignore_index=True)`.

Comment: i feel like a facepalm moment. Thanks!